# jQuery find td with class name and change the text based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table and i want to filter all td values based on class name  and then if td holds specific text replace it with new text. below is my current code. its not working properly and updating all the td's .
please advice how to proceed.

## html

```
 <td class="actionclass">' . $page->action . '</td>
```

## jquery

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
    var ratingTdText = $(this).find('td.actionclass').text();
    if ((ratingTdText == "saved block")) {
        this.innerHTML = 'changed';
    }
});
```

===

## update

```
              $("tbody tr td.actionclass").each(function() {       
                var ratingTdText = $(this).text();
                console.log(ratingTdText);
                if(($(this).is(':contains("new")')) || ($(this).is(':contains("saved")'))) {
                        (this).text().replace("top", "TopBar"); 
                         (this).text().replace("left", "LeftBar"); 
                          (this).text().replace("bottom", "BottomBar"); 

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 6):

`this` refers to `TR` element not the `TD`, change the selector in the `find()` and your code will work

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
    var ratingTd = $(this).find('td.actionclass');//Refers to TD element
    if (ratingTd.text() == "saved block") {
        ratingTd.text('changed');
    }
});
```

*OR*

```
//get all td with actionclass in table
$("tbody tr td.actionclass").each(function() {       
    var ratingTdText = $(this).text();
    if (ratingTdText == "saved block") {
        this.innerHTML = 'changed';
    }
});
```

---

Your code can be improved using `.filter()`

```
//get all td with actionclass in table
$("tbody tr td.actionclass").filter(function() {       
    return $(this).text() == "saved block";
}).text('changed');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.innerHTML = 'changed';
```

Should be

```
 ratingTdText.innerHTML = 'changed';
```

You shouldn't use `this` inside because it is pointing to `row` not your `td`